# How to happily accept a job application rejection?

Tags: meaning

I was rejected for a quote (Angebot) I sent for a small job, but will hopefully be working together with the company in the future on other projects. I'd like to say that it's unfortunate that I was rejected but that I'm looking forward to collaborating in the future.

In this sensitive situation I am not sure if the sense of the words I'm saying is actually conveying the attitude I have - which is 'oh well, no worries, thanks for considering me and I'm happy to work together in the future'.

Currently, I have a sentence as follows:

> Schade, dass es [the offer] nicht geklappt hat, aber ich freue mich auf weitere Zusammenarbeit!

Is Schade really something I am angry or extremely disappointed about? Can an Angebot klappen? Am I being presumptuous in saying that we will have weitere Zusammenarbeit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sentence is completely ok. You would not express great anger or disappointment with the word *Schade* but rather a little disappointment, and that is what you (imho) *should* express.

I would not try to find a stronger word for this (e.g. Ich bin sehr enttäuscht, dass es nicht geklappt hat) as that makes you look a little bit unforgiving or even nitpicking.

And **geklappt** can be perfectly used in this context, in deed it is used very often in the context of contracts / negotiations / etc.

Comment: Beside of this not commenting might be fine too. I wouldn't be happy to get 100 letters telling me "schade, vielleicht beim nächsten Mal" — You did not apply to don't get the job. Of course, its sad.

Comment: You are right, but as far as I understand, it is not "that" kind of job, where you get hired, get a regular salary. It is just something you hire a freelancer for (e.g. write a little application, develop a special website, etc)

Comment: I would expect such a letter even if I hire a freelancer. Usually you are talking to >1 freelance to get this job done. And of course, also a freelancer is sad to don't get the job. I don't want to be rude, just pointing out that silence and retry next time might be more successful.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine but I don't consider "es" to refer to "offer". I don't think that an offer itself can work out. But when referring to the whole situation and that this just doesn't worked out, that's fine I guess.
Since you refer to future cooperations in the second part, "es" could also be understood as to refer to "Zusammenarbeit", meaning particularly "cooperation with regard to that specific offer".

If you specifically would like to refer to the offer, I'd probably say something along the lines:

> Schade, dass Sie mein Angebot nicht angenommen haben.
>   Schade, dass Sie sich gegen mein Angebot entschieden haben.
>   Schade, dass Ihnen mein Angebot nicht zugesagt hat.

As of the future cooperations, it depends on what the situation really is. At the end of the day, you will have to consider how good the relation to them is and phrase the sentence based on that. But this has nothing to do with the German language whatsoever.

That being said, assuming that you've already had some cooperations with them in the past and that there are upcoming projects in the near future, the sentence is absolutely fine. Besides, you could then add "diesmal" to the first part of the sentence.

On the other hand, if you're just guessing that other projects could be accepted by them, I'd probably say something like this:

> ..., aber ich würde mich freuen, wenn wir bei anderen Projekten zusammenarbeiten könnten.

The key is here to use the subjunctive as you imply that you're not already convinced of getting other offers accepted. By this, you can avoid being understood as presumptuous.

Finally, just for the sake of giving a complete answer, the word *schade* is correct and a very common way to convey that you consider something as being unfortunate.